# Discord.py bot to move a certain user to a different voice chat automatically

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently writing a bot using the discord.py library.
Is there any way for the bot (script) to move users to a different voice channel automatically?
For example you type the command for user X to be automatically moved to a specific voice chat and every time user X joins a voice channel, he gets moved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Just use [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) event and [move_to](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.move_to) function.
For example:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener() # for cogs. If you haven't implemented cogs use `@client.event`
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after): # also remove `self` argument if you haven't implemented cogs
    if after.channel is not None: # check if member join to new voice channel
        channel = something # you can specify voice channel here. For example use `self.client.get_channel(id)` to get channel by ID
        await member.move_to(channel)
```